# Re-group 2D coordinates of pairs in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, python-3.x, data-structures

How can I rearrange `[(0, 4), (1, 3)]` to `(0, 1), (4, 3)`, in other words group first coordinates together and second coordinates together (order maintained left to right). I need to do this for a large list of, exampled below

```
c = [[(0, 4), (1, 3)],
     [(0, 4), (1, 5)],
     [(1, 3), (2, 2)],
     [(1, 3), (2, 4)],
     [(1, 5), (2, 2)],
     [(1, 5), (2, 6)],
     ...]
```

So that the end result is

```
[[(0, 1), (4, 3)],
 [(0, 1), (4, 5)],
 [(1, 2), (3, 2)],
 [(1, 2), (3, 4)],
 [(1, 2), (5, 2)],
 [(1, 2), (5, 6)],
 ...
 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
end_result = [[(w, y), (x, z)] for [(w, x), (y, z)] in c]
```

?

Comment: Fantastic! I tourchured `zip()` too much and overlooked the basics.